# Separate column into multiple rows and fill to the left, in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I've got a very long list of annotated genes. They are annotated at varying levels "A", "B", "C", etc. Each level has a different name and in some cases a different format. I'd like to keep the names of each level intact. In R, the text document gets imported as 1 column, and I'd like to separate A, B, C, and D rows into columns. Rows are in order, meaning "B Level2" is listed after the application A Level1 category and above "C Level3" category. "#" separate level D, from the next A levell category. 
SO, after each "#" I'd like to separate the A, B, C, and D rows into separate columns. THEN fill in the column to the left with the level category name above. 
Given this example df:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c("A<b>Level1</b>", "B", "B  <b>Level2</b>", "C    02000 Level3 [BR:ko02000]", "C    02010 Level3 [PATH:ko02010]", "D      Level4; K15551  tauA; taurine transport system substrate-binding protein", "D      Level4; K15551  tauA; taurine transport system substrate-binding protein", "D      Level4; K15551  tauA; taurine transport system substrate-binding protein"))
```

The output needs to look like this:

```
A   B   C   D
A<b>Level1</b>  B  <b>Level2</b>    C    02000 Level3 [BR:ko02000]  NA
A<b>Level1</b>  B  <b>Level2</b>    C    02010 Level3 [PATH:ko02010]    D      Level4; K15551  tauA; taurine transport system substrate-binding protein
A<b>Level1</b>  B  <b>Level2</b>    C    02010 Level3 [PATH:ko02010]    D      Level4; K15551  tauA; taurine transport system substrate-binding protein
A<b>Level1</b>  B  <b>Level2</b>    C    02010 Level3 [PATH:ko02010]    D      Level4; K15551  tauA; taurine transport system substrate-binding protein
```

So far, I'm trying to dplyr and tidyr to separate() the input df, but I can't seem to get it to work. 
Suggestions?? thoughts??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest using a list of data frames, created using `split`:

```
split(df, substr(df$x, 1, 1))
```

If you really must have it how your showed it:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% group_by(id = substr(x, 1, 1)) %>%
       mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
       spread(id, x) %>%
       fill(-row)
```

Comment: When I use the second solution here, I get this error message: "Error in setNames(as.list(seq_along(vars)), vars) : object 'A' not found"

Comment: It should work, but see the edit for a more general version